# How to make annotations static without removing using pypdf2

Tags: python, pypdf

I have so many annotations in my pdf, which is all editable and I would like to convert it non editable, I couldn't figure out how to make it static, I used below code but it completely removed the annotations.

```
import PyPDF2

with open('drawing.pdf', 'rb') as pdf_obj:
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_obj)
    out = PyPDF2.PdfWriter()
    for page in pdf.pages:
        if page.annotations:
            page.annotations.clear()    # This line is removing the annotations, here I would like to make it static
        out.add_page(page)
with open('output.pdf', 'wb') as f: 
    out.write(f)
```

I do not wanted to use pypdftk since it is os dependent and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27023043/generate-flattened-pdf-with-python) is all about form fields

**UPDATE 1**

To be more precise I am trying to flatten `indirect objects`

Comment: @KJ probably yes

Comment: @KJ But my case is not form fields and it can be any layers

Comment: @KJ Thank you understood and trying to solve this via [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)